# Atualização de valores da variável no laço de repetição

Tags: java, variáveis

Fiz um código simples de operação de saque e depósito em uma variável. O código funciona e atende as operações de saque e depósito normalmente, acontece que quando eu quero fazer **uma nova operação**, o valor que me retorna é o mesmo que o saldo inicial, e não a atualização de valores.

Por exemplo, se eu coloquei saldo inicial 1000, digito 2 para sacar e coloco 500, o valor atualizado deveria me retornar 500 e realizar o cálculo em cima desses 500, mas na nova operação de nº 2 (sacar), ele retira os 500 da variável inicial (1000), e me retorna um valor errado por conta disso. Ou seja, me retorna *1000 - 500 = R$ 500,00* e o correto deveria ser *1000 - 500 - 500 = R$ 0,00.*

Esse valor não poderia já ser atualizado automaticamente no comando `continue`, que retorna ao laço?

Segue o meu código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    double saldoInicial, saldoFinal = 0, valorSaque, valorDeposito;
    int operacao;

    System.out.println("Digite o saldo inicial: ");
    saldoInicial = input.nextDouble();

    do {
        System.out.println("Digite o código da operação (1-deposito, 2-saque, 3-encerrar): ");
        operacao = input.nextInt();

        switch (operacao) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Digite o valor a ser depositado");
            valorDeposito = input.nextDouble();
            saldoFinal = saldoInicial + valorDeposito;
            continue;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Digite o valor do saque: ");
            valorSaque = input.nextDouble();
            saldoFinal = saldoInicial - valorSaque;
            continue;
        }

    } while (operacao != 3);

    if (saldoFinal == 0) {
        System.out.println("CONTA ZERADA");
    } else if (saldoFinal > 0) {
        System.out.println("CONTA PREFERENCIAL");
    } else {
        System.out.println("CONTA ESTOURADA");
    }
    System.out.printf("Saldo da conta: R$ %.2f%n", saldoFinal);

    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não dá o resultado esperado não está funcionando e não atende ao requisito.

Não vou falar dos vários problemas neste código, nem reclamar do uso de `double` para valor monetário porque é exercício, mas fique ligado nisso pra não achar que o código está perfeito depois de arrumar o problema específico da pergunta.

Quando você faz um depósito ou um saque está alterando a variável `saldoFinal` se baseando no `saldoInicial` e mais ou menos o valor digitado, ou seja, não importa quantas operações você faça ele será feito no saldo final sem considerar o saldo final, considera sempre o saldo inicial. Você não disse mas a primeira operação dá certo, por coincidência, as outras é que dão errado.

Na verdade o conceito está errado, não existe isso de saldo inicial e saldo final, saldo é saldo, pare de tratar essas coisas como se fossem duas coisas e passará dar certo, o saldo inicial é só um saldo que em vez de somar ou diminuir é só atribuído e depois você opera sempre no saldo e tudo dá certo. Se não conceitua certo a solução acaba saindo errado, começa desconsiderar ou adicionar "variáveis" indevidas no problema.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        int operacao = 0;
        System.out.println("Digite o saldo inicial: ");
        double saldo = input.nextDouble();
        do {
            System.out.println("Digite o código da operação (1-deposito, 2-saque, 3-encerrar): ");
            operacao = input.nextInt();
            switch (operacao) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Digite o valor a ser depositado");
                saldo += input.nextDouble();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Digite o valor do saque: ");
                saldo -= input.nextDouble();
                break;
            }
        } while (operacao != 3);
        if (saldo == 0) System.out.println("CONTA ZERADA");
        else if (saldo > 0) System.out.println("CONTA PREFERENCIAL");
        else System.out.println("CONTA ESTOURADA");
        System.out.printf("Saldo da conta: R$ %.2f%n", saldo);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3dQG5c). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/BankExamplejava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/BankExample.java).

Fique atento porque eu corrigi algumas coisas que citei mas não tudo.

Comment: Quando já chega falando na cara "os vários problemas do código" pode soar um pouco agressivo pra quem estava do zero no seu próprio esforço, na unha do código, conseguir o resultado esperado. O jeito introduzido parecia que o código estava em Nárnia e completamente incorreto, mas vi somente ajustes aliada à solução :). Tirando a questão do Double ao fator monetário, poderia apontar pra mim que outros problemas seriam esses? Mas o aperfeiçoamento e melhoria sim, isso realmente. Inclusive agradeço pelos toques, como por exemplo o cálculo direto no input, no qual ainda eu não tinha conhecimento.

Comment: Cada um pode interpretar como quiser, eu poderia não falar nada, você achar que está tudo em ordem e passar o resto da vida se iludindo, algumas pessoas gostam disto, outra preferem aprender fazer certo, eu dou preferência para quem é do segundo caso, mas como não conheço todo mundo não tenho selecionar a quem responder. Não teria espaço para ficar listando cada detalhe e explicar com propriedade, algumas coisas envolvem conceitos mais avançados e complicados, e geralmente resolvemos problemas pontuais, eu só alerto pra pessoa não acreditar que está tudo ok.. Viu que consertei alguns? Outro:

Comment: Seu código quebra se digitar algo inválido.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, você está tendo problemas por conta dessa variável de saldo inicial, se eu colocar um saldo inicial, não efetuar nenhuma operação, meu saldo inicial será o meu saldo final... Uma opção, é somente trabalhar com a variável saldo final, seu código fica mais simples, abaixo um exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    double saldoFinal = 0, valorSaque, valorDeposito;
    int operacao;

    System.out.println("Digite o saldo inicial: ");
    saldoFinal = input.nextDouble();

    do {
        System.out.println("Digite o código da operação (1-deposito, 2-saque, 3-encerrar): ");
        operacao = input.nextInt();

        switch (operacao) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Digite o valor a ser depositado");
            valorDeposito = input.nextDouble();
            saldoFinal += valorDeposito;
            continue;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Digite o valor do saque: ");
            valorSaque = input.nextDouble();
            saldoFinal -= valorSaque;
            continue;
        }

    } while (operacao != 3);

    if (saldoFinal == 0) {
        System.out.println("CONTA ZERADA");
    } else if (saldoFinal > 0) {
        System.out.println("CONTA PREFERENCIAL");
    } else {
        System.out.println("CONTA ESTOURADA");
    }
    System.out.printf("Saldo da conta: R$ %.2f%n", saldoFinal);

    input.close();
}
```